# Kubernetes volume snapshot Vs. sql backup?

Tags: database, docker, kubernetes, volume, snapshot

I am running database inside Kubernetes pod. i am planning to run K8s job to take automatic backup of databases from pod.

There is also i can write shell script to take snapshot of volume(PV).

which method will be better to use? in emergency which one will save time restore data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Stash by AppsCode](https://appscode.com/products/stash/) which is a great solution to backup Kubernetes volumes.

For supported versions check [here](https://github.com/appscode/stash#supported-versions)

> Stash by AppsCode is a Kubernetes operator for restic. If you are
>   running production workloads in Kubernetes, you might want to take
>   backup of your disks. Traditional tools are too complex to setup and
>   maintain in a dynamic compute environment like Kubernetes. restic is a
>   backup program that is fast, efficient and secure with few moving
>   parts. Stash is a CRD controller for Kubernetes built around restic to
>   address these issues.
>   Using Stash, you can backup Kubernetes volumes mounted in following
>   types of workloads:
>
> Deployment, DaemonSet, ReplicaSet, ReplicationController, StatefulSet

After installing stash using [Script](https://appscode.com/products/stash/0.8.3/setup/install/#using-script) or [HELM](https://appscode.com/products/stash/0.8.3/setup/install/#using-helm) you would want to follow 
Instructions for [Backup](https://appscode.com/products/stash/0.8.3/guides/backup/) and [Restore](https://appscode.com/products/stash/0.8.3/guides/restore/) if you are not familiar

I find it very useful